# Why is my MacBook Pro M1 not using swap?

Tags: memory

I've had a number of "your system has run out of application memory" crashes recently. I now keep the Activity Monitor running and swap is permanently pegged at 0.

[image]

I've checked vm.compressor_mode:

```
sysctl -a vm.compressor_mode
vm.compressor_mode: 4
```

Checking vm.swapusage:

```
sysctl vm.swapusage         
vm.swapusage: total = 0.00M  used = 0.00M  free = 0.00M  (encrypted)
```

What else can I try?

Currently running Sonoma 14.0 but happened on the previous version as well. This is fairly new (a couple months) as I don't remember it happening over the past year that I've had this machine.

Comment: Three questions: Is your SSD nearly full? Are you running macOS from an external drive? Does the Terminal command `mount` show `/System/Volumes/VM` (about the 4th line)?

Comment: Thanks @Gilby. 364GB free, only internal drive, mount does have /System/Volumes/VM yes.

Comment: Your memory usage is quite light. You have very low memory compression, low memory pressure, and over 1/4 of your memory is allocated to cached files. You don't need to use any swap. The cause of your "run out of memory crashes" might not be related to lack of swap.  Is it the same app that crashes? Or is it a kernel panic, taking down the whole system? Might be worth trying to get some diagnostics from the logs when this happens.

Comment: It's not initially a crash. It opens the dialog with the above memory message, and a set of applications that I can close. But it's frozen, so I'm typically unable to select and close them. After a period it crashes. I'll check the diagnostic message and the logs next time it happens.